# Using a Floating Action Button with ListView in a Fragment with Navigation

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I am new to using Java and Android Studio and I'm stumped. I have created an application with bottom navigation and that functions fine. I'm trying to use a floating action button to create list entries into a ListView. I've created an adapter for the ListView and an XML for it but when I actually click on the tab, nothing shows up. I think the issue may lie in using onCreate vs. onCreateView, but since I'm new I'm not really sure what I should put where. As my code stands, the fragment loads with nothing showing except for the title of the fragment. I stopped using onCreateView and put everything under onCreate because my fragment was crashing. Any help would be appreciated.

Fragment Java:

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

```
private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;
private FragmentDashboardBinding binding;
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView ListView;
EditText editText;
public String test;

public void onCreate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    listItems.add("Let's see where this ends up");
    ListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View view) {
                                           switch (view.getId()) {
                                               case R.id.fab:
                                                   listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                                                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
    );
    ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    dashboardViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
    binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();


    final TextView textView = binding.textDashboard;

    dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}}
```

Fragment XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_first8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="153dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="154dp"
    android:text="@string/title_dashboard"
    android:textColor="@color/teal_font"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_first8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: the views of your fragment are wrapped inside a `ViewGroup` right? e.g. `ConstraintLayout` or `LinearLayout`

Comment: If you are using `ConstraintLayout`, use constraints properly. For instance, constraints for `TextView` @+id/text_dashboard are set to fill the screen

Comment: Yes they are under a ConstraintLayout.